# How to have relative paths navigable in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, babeljs

I have a JS project with babel configuration, and it's configured to support relative paths. Instead of doing this:

```
import Class from '../../../../somePath/Class';
```

Writing the code in a more clean way:

```
import Class from 'app/somePath/Class';
```

**babel.config.js**

```
const plugins = [
  [require('babel-plugin-module-resolver'), { root: ["./app/"] }],
];
```

That's all great, but I struggle with navigation trough files. For example when using CMD+Click on path, to navigate to file doesn't work on relative paths.

Is there a way to support navigations for relative paths in VSCode?

**UPDATE**

I tried the method suggested by **@rioV** and add [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links) configuration to my project:

***myapp/.vscode/settings.json***

Added the following to project settings:

```
  "html-related-links.include": {
    "javascript": [
      { "find": "import [^ ]+ from '((?=app/).+?)';", "filePath": "/$1.js" },
      { "find": "import [^ ]+ from '((?!app/).+?)';", "filePath": "$1.js" }
    ]
  },
```

***User/settings.json***

Also have included `html-related-links.alwaysShow to true` in the User settings:

```
"html-related-links.alwaysShow": true,
"html-related-links.fileroot": [
    "./app"
],
```

And still doesn't seem to navigate when clicking the file path.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links) v0.6.0. Now the name is no longer correct because it also can show related files in other file types.

If you add the following to your `project/.vscode/settings.json`

```
  "html-related-links.include": {
    "javascript": [
      { "find": "import [^ ]+ from '((?=src/).+?)';", "filePath": "/$1.js" },
      { "find": "import [^ ]+ from '((?!src/).+?)';", "filePath": "$1.js" }
    ]
  }
```

The imports that start with `src/` are treated relative to the file root folder (most likely the workspace root). If you have a different file root you also need to modify the `html-related-links.fileroot` setting.

The other imports (do not start with `src/`) are relative to the current file.

Because you use JavaScript files you also have to set `html-related-links.alwaysShow` to `true` in the **User** settings or the (Multi Root) **Workspace** settings.

In the **Explorer** View Container there is a view named `HTML Related Links`. If you click on one of the entries that file will be opened if it exists.

From VSC v1.46 you can drag/drop views to a different location

Comment: I followed each step of your description, but still doesn't want to navigate to file on click

Comment: @ValeriCrudu: What is your project/Workspace directory? What is the path of your App? If all paths in the JS files are **relative** to the Workspace directory then don't set the `fileroot` setting. Do you see the `HTML Related Links` Extension in the Extension Sidebar?  Do you see the `HTML Related Links` View in the `Explorer` sidebar? What does the tooltip show you when you hover over an entry in the `HTML Related Links` View? If you look at the settings JSON files are the `html-related-links.*` entries **not** greyed out? Do you see any squigle lines in the JSON files?

Comment: I had an similar issue, but for JSON files referencing JS files, so i added `"json": [{"find": "\"script\": \"((?!src/).+?)\"", "filePath": "$1"}]`. Works perfectly!